# chrome needs to restore tabs on every reboot

Tags: google-chrome

I am running chrome on ubuntu 16.04. Every time I reboot my machine and reopen chrome, chrome tells me that it was not closed properly and needs to restore my tabs. I tried disabling chrome's ability to run background apps, as noted [here](https://www.ryananddebi.com/2015/08/18/ubuntu-linux-kde-chrome-didnt-shut-down-correctly-error/), with no success.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use chrome .. but it this a problem at all? Sounds like chrome is just restoring the tabs you had open before closing it. Usually there should be an option in the start settings of the browser where you can turn off this behavior. At least with Firefox e.g. on startup you have the options to start with a certain page, an empty tab or to restore last session tabs.

Comment: You are correct, you can select whether to start with an empty page, an empty tab or to restore last sessions tabs. I have chosen to restore last sessions tabs. The problem is that because chrome shuts down improperly , as a result of a reboot, my last session tabs do not appear. Instead, I receive an error screen and am asked if I would like tot manually restore my tabs (see the link in the post for images). Oddly enough, I have had this same issue with firefox as well.

Comment: I'm hitting this error as well on my Ubuntu 17.10 VM.

Comment: Could you please disable all browser add-ons in Chrome close it, wait about 10 seconds and run `pidof chrome` if there is any Chrome process left over?

Comment: Chrome should have added an option to always restore, instead of asking every time.

Answer (score 5):

I too see this problem with chrome not shutting down properly on Ubuntu 17.10.  In my case it turned out to be the forecastfox extension.  When it's running and I close chrome I can see in system monitor that the browser has not shut down completely and problems do occur when I start chrome the next time from chrome crashing to tabs needing to restore.  If I disable forecastfox chrome shuts down fine and I see no problems the next time I open it.

Comment: I upvote this answer because browser extension is the cause in my case too. I used Browsec for VPN and disabling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've been seeing the same behaviour in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and no matter of debugging, tweaking, reading articles or trying anything fixed it.

I did however literally just find that if I logout *before* I reboot then it's fine. **Not** exactly a "solution", however it seems to appease the Chrome gods and allow it to exit gracefully.

Hope  that is of some use

Comment: I kind of like having all my tabs restored upon rebooting. So I consider it less a bug and more an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround does it for me Chrome v80, Ubuntu 18.04:
Add a custome command to shut down Chrome gracefully before rebooting.
What I did is to append to ~/.bash_aliases:

```
alias res="pkill --oldest chrome; sleep 3; sudo reboot"
```

Sleep is needed since it takes a bit time to shut chrome down. Then every time I want to reboot, I just run res from terminal. "res" is less typing for me as well.

Note: I think there are more proper ways to run command before rebooting. Please feel free to update.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an out of date Chromecast extension. Removing it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like having all my tabs restored upon rebooting. So I consider it less a bug and more an undocumented feature.

You can simply click the `X` to close the Chrome (or Firefox) Window and if it prompts, confirm the prompt "Close all tabs?". Then upon rebooting it will not prompt you to reopen previous tabs.

Answer (score 0):

`--wait` flag instead of `sleep 3` work for me

`killall chrome --wait && reboot`

Answer (score 0):

In my case running `Pop!_OS 21.04` and `Google Chrome 96.0.4664.45`, in the top bar there was a chrome status icon, I unchecked the option `Let Chrome run in the background` and that seemed to solved it.